# python pandas how to extract number from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an dataframe  and I want to extract only number from string and appoint theme another new row.

dataframe:

```
 type
gp250,sp280
```

expected result for dataframe:

```
type   price
gp      25
sp      280
```

Comment: @Psidom yes Sir

Comment: Please elaborate the logic of extracting numbers. You also have a `$` sign, so it's not entirely number.

Comment: the logic will be need to only extract number. we can user `.str.replace` method for remove $ from original  dataframe

Comment: again I edited my question

Comment: Please also make it clear about the pattern of strings. Will the number always at the end of strings ? Can there be more than one number in each string ?

Comment: yes number will be sometime after string or before string like 45skd or skd45

Comment: please include those cases and elaborate if there can be multiple numbers in each string.

Comment: Assume number will always last. like SDF4582,DFUS586255,AD1582.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract the consecutive digits of the string and then `explode` to transform the result into multiple rows.

```
import re
df["type"].apply(lambda x: re.findall("([0-9]+)", x)).explode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have the pattern with non digit characters followed by numbers, you can first `split` and `explode` joined string into separate rows and then use `.str.extract` to extract non digit pattern (`\D*`) and number (`\d*`) into different columns:

```
df['type'].str.split(',').explode().str.extract('(?P<type>\D*)(?P<price>\d*)', expand=True)
  type price
0   gp   250
0   sp   280
```